# Is that possible to have multiple servers in the same group in the Sequelize CLI config file?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I've just started using Sequelize and Sequelize CLI.
Is that possible to have multiple servers in the same group in the config file? For example,  I would like to connect 60 MySQL servers that need to divide into 3 groups. So development/test/production each group will have 20 servers.

I tried to setup the config.js like this but it doesn't work

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "MyPASSWORD",
    "database": "X",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "MyPASSWORD",
    "database": "X",
    "host": "10.1.1.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "MyPASSword",
    "database": "A",
    "host": "10.1.1.3",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
}
```

I am very new to NodeJS and Sequelize CLI, any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are trying to configure db connection for various environments like development/test/production, right ?? I dont see any problems here. 
Settings should be applicable as per the target environment.

Comment: @rootExplorr I would like to connect  60 MySQL servers that need to divide into 3 groups. So development/test/production each group will have 20 servers

Comment: So yes that configuration will also be possible. Actually for each group if there are 20 servers then it is not you that would have to manage the 20 server, instead there would be a load balaning among those 20 servers of each group. You just have to connect to the common db url for a specific group of 20 servers.

Comment: @rootExplorr Do you mean I can have a master running MySQL replication to all other 19 slaves? So I only need the MySQL master information in my config?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Why would you want to manage all 60 servers from code, too tedious a task and absolutely worthless.

Comment: @rootExplorr This is the requirement from the developer team. We have 20 BE developers' VM and I have to make sure all of them have the same schema. We don't have replication in our development environment. Can I have the hosts group and then I can push the schema change to all 20 VM concurrently?